# Elliptic Curve Crypto

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography

I had just read a primer about ECC, I see how it can be complicated.

Something I haven't been able to determine is what information does the client machine get to help decrypt the data?

The whole exchange part I'm not sure about.

Comment: Look into El Gamal and Diffie-Hellman. El Gamal is used for public-key encryption. Diffie-Hellman is a key exchange protocol. The details of the exchange depends on the algorithm. Elliptic curves are used by the algorithms to generate cyclic groups.

Answer (score 5):

As an example, lets look at Elliptic-Curve-Diffie-Hellman (ECDH).

**Alice**

- Ephemeral key pair generation
- Select a private key $n_A \in [1, n-1]$
- Calculate the public key $Q_A = n_A P$
- Alice ships $Q_A$ to Bob

**Bob**

- Ephemeral key pair generation
- Select a private key $n_B \in [1, n-1]$
- Calculate the public key $Q_B = n_B P$
- Bob ships $Q_B$ to Alice

**Each party calculates shared key**

- Alice: Shared key computation $K= n_AQ_B$
- Bob: Shared key computation $K= n_BQ_A$
- Consistency: $K=n_AQ_B=n_An_B P=n_BQ_A$ (they have the same shared key, while having their own private component)

Notice that they each keep their private key to themselves.

Also note, in order to break this scheme, you would have to solve the Elliptic-Curve-Discrete-Log-Problem (ECDLP).

**Elliptic Curve Discrete Logarithm Problem (ECDLP)**:

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a finite field $F_q$. Suppose $P$ is some point of $E( F_q )$ and let $Q$ be a point in $\left< P \right>$. Find an integer $t$ such that $Q = [t] P$.

Comment: ECDLP is different than just DLP?

Comment: Yes, it is the Elliptic Curve variant of DLP, but it is different. See: http://www.crm.cat/Paginas/Conferences/0607/ContentSecurity/Slides/Leprevost.pdf

Comment: Yes, it is very helpful, however, I get a message saying I can't upvote yet because my reputation is under 15. Sorry, but I appreciate the response!

Comment: Trying to understand what is actually available in ECC to eavesdroppers that is/can be used in "cracking" the private key. In RSA it seems like all you need are the factors of a semi prime then you're pretty much free to read the data.

With ECC how is it comparable to what is needed to decrypt?

I have watched videos, read some material but is there something in specific that needs to be calculated that can then be used in this process.

In RSA, even if you don't understand what is happening, the key is the SemiPrime factors. So, from what I am reading it's solving for ECDLP?

Comment: Solving ECDLP I am sure is next to impossible, at least, Dec 2013... In the future as advancements are made this may change. 

Is it possible to say "Well if you can determine "X" then the rest is straight forward" X being this "problem" that is used in ECC to create the complexity.

Comment: You are essentially trying to break the point multiplication. See update. You should now have enough votes to vote. Regards

Comment: Ok so if we had a magic algorithm that took a semiprime instantly spit out the factor(s) would it be a vulnerability to ECCor RSA or both?

Comment: If you had a program that could find the factors of the product of two primes, it would only affect RSA.

Comment: I see ok. I also assume that since no efficient algorithm that RSA remains safe but even if there was one does that mean it's easy to decrypt RSA or wwould it render it useless at that time?

Comment: WHat typically happens when a new algorithm comes out, is that it works for up to a certain size of number, but then cannot handle an increase. If you look at the factoring challenge and the general number field sieve, it is currently as good as it gets until someone figures out a better and more efficient algorithm. That is what makes these so called trapdoor functions so useful.

Comment: It's an interesting math problem for sure but just because a solution may work that doesn't make RSA broken does it?

Comment: If someone were to make factoring easy, it is effectively broken and would have to be replaced by another asymmetric systems (and there are others - like ECC, NTRU...). Can you accept answers now?

Comment: sorry! I'm on a mobile device how do I accept?

Comment: I'll read more about trap doors thanks for so much info

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an answer, but really a comment, but I don't have a high enough reputation to comment:

If you're talking about [ECIES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme)
then, the client Bob, would already have the private key (which is a secret that is kept to himself) to decrypt data that was sent by Alice.

Note the that private and public key are related to each other, the public key can be given to anyone (namely, Alice); the private key is kept secret.